# Написать XPath, который выбирает все элементы от и до

Tags: html, html5, xpath, web-scraping

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>First H2</h2>
<p>First P</p>
<div>First DIV</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>

<h2>Second H2</h2>
<p>Second P</p>
<div>Second DIV</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>

<h2>Third H2</h2>
<p>Third P</p>
<div>Third DIV</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

В общем есть такая веб страница.
Я хочу написать XPath выражение, которое вернет список с 3 элементов, в каждый список войдут все элементы, которые начинаются от `h2` и заканчиваются перед следующим `h2`

В общем нужный XPath вернет три элемента с этого примера
1.

```
<h2>First H2</h2>
<p>First P</p>
<div>First DIV</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
```

2.

```
<h2>Second H2</h2>
<p>Second P</p>
<div>Second DIV</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
```

3.

```
<h2>Third H2</h2>
<p>Third P</p>
<div>Third DIV</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
```

Помогите составить данный XPath. Спасибо.

Comment: Не знаю насчет Xpath 2, в один  - только циклом по h2

Comment: циклом? ну h2 извлечь просто, но нужно как-то извлечь всю информацию от открытого тега h2 до следующего тега h2.

Comment: @splash58 можете показать пример, который вы имели ввиду?

Comment: Это не xhtml - тег `meta` не закрыт.

Comment: Обновил теги, ссори.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если делать циклом, то можно использовать вот такой Xpath

```
. | ./following-sibling::*[count(following-sibling::h2)=<rest>]
```

Точка - это текущий элемент, а

`<rest>` надо заменить на количество оставшихся h2 после текущего. Те в примере в первой итерации должно быть 2, в следующей 1 и в последней 0

код на php

```
$h2s = $xml->xpath('//h2');
foreach($h2s as $k => $h2) {
    $xs = $h2->xpath('. | ./following-sibling::*[count(following-sibling::h2)='.(count($h2s)-$k-1).']');
    foreach($xs as $x) {
        echo $x . "<br>\n<br>\n";
    }
    echo "<br>\n<br>\n";
```

Comment: `. | ` - а что это означает?

Comment: текущий элемент или ... чтоб сам h2 вошел

Comment: Извините, вот я вбиваю такое в хром на моем примере, и ничео не работает. `. | ./following-sibling::*[count(following-sibling::h2)=2]`

Comment: что именно не работает? я вот даже на php накидал, чтоб вас не обмануть :)  все вывелось

Comment: `//h2/./following-sibling::*[count(following-sibling::h2)=0]` - вот так нужно, верно?

Comment: То, что написано у меня - это для програмного кода в цикл. Если проверять в chrome `//h2[1] |  //h2[1]/following-sibling::*[count(following-sibling::h2)=2]` так первый блок

Comment: А если второй элемент в хроме проверить, то какие цифры нужно поменять в этом выражении?

Comment: //h2[2] | //h2[2]/following-sibling::*[count(following-sibling::h2)=1]

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98920/discussion-between-serhii-and-splash58).