# как прописать XPath для поиска по другому XPath

Tags: xpath, scrapy, web-scraping

```
➜ scrapy shell https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026293/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-xpath-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE/1026326
```

открывается наш ipython терминал и мы вводим

```
mainbar = response.xpath("//div[@id='mainbar']")
In [2]: type(mainbar)                                                                                                                       
Out[2]: scrapy.selector.unified.SelectorList
```

В чем проблема и вопрос.
Вопрос в том, что я не могу понять, как выполнить поиск по икспасу в этом элементе.
В данном диве находятся другие дивы, параграфы и прочие хтмл теги с информацией. Я хочу прописать икспас для поиска именно по содержимому `mainbar`

```
mainbar.xpath("//div[@class='question']")
```

так? или вот так?

```
mainbar.xpath(".//div[@class='question']")
```

или вот так

```
mainbar.xpath("./div[@class='question']")
```

или так

```
mainbar.xpath("/div[@class='question']")
```

Как правильно искать содержимое по уже найденному XPath элементу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо, так

```
mainbar.xpath(".//div[@class='question']")
```

Точка нужна, чтобы искать от текущего элемента, иначе будет искать от корня

Если поставить один слэш, то поиск буде только на верхнем уровне. Чтобы в любом месте дерева, надо два слэша